# remove double quotes from Json return data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery to get Json data, but the data it display has double quotes. It there a function to remove it?

```
$('div#ListingData').text(JSON.stringify(data.data.items[0].links[1].caption))
```

it returns:

```
"House"
```

How can I remove the double quote? Cheers.

Comment: javascript replace function should work

Answer (score 69):

Use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var test = "\"House\"";
console.log(test);
console.log(test.replace(/\"/g, ""));  

// "House"
// House
```

Note the `g` on the end means "global" (replace all).

Comment: Awesome! This what exactly what I was looking for. I replace the double quotes, and try with some characters. Nice! thanks!!

Comment: Regex, although it works, can cause a lot of memory waste. I think that the user should either just not use JSON.stringify() or if it is a JSON response that is just a sentence, use JSON.parse(). Those regexes add up when things scale. Just saying.

Comment: Does not trim starting/ending quotes. It strips all quotes.

Answer (score 25):

For niche needs when you know your data like your example ...  this works :

```
JSON.parse(this_is_double_quoted);

JSON.parse("House");  // for example
```

Answer (score 8):

The `stringfy` method is not for parsing JSON, it's for turning an object into a JSON string.

The JSON is parsed by jQuery when you load it, you don't need to parse the data to use it. Just use the string in the data:

```
$('div#ListingData').text(data.data.items[0].links[1].caption);
```

Answer (score 7):

Someone [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV3_yX-5PoAhWalnIEHYckA6oQFjACegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fqawithexperts.com%2Fquestions%2F300%2Fhow-to-remove-quotation-marks-double-quotes-from-string-usin&usg=AOvVaw2oTSEYScLcyQ8q7QwQ8EIZ) suggested using `eval()` to remove the quotes from a string. Don't do that, that's just begging for code injection.

Another way to do this that I don't see listed here is using:

```
let message = JSON.stringify(your_json_here); // "Hello World"
console.log(JSON.parse(message))              // Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had this question, but in my case I didn't want to use a regex, because my JSON value may contain quotation marks. Hopefully my answer will help others in the future.

I solved this issue by using a standard string slice to remove the first and last characters. This works for me, because I used `JSON.stringify()` on the `textarea` that produced it and as a result, I know that I'm always going to have the `"`s at each end of the string.

In this generalized example, `response` is the JSON object my AJAX returns, and `key` is the name of my JSON key.

```
response.key.slice(1, response.key.length-1)
```

I used it like this with a regex `replace` to preserve the line breaks and write the content of that key to a paragraph block in my HTML:

```
$('#description').html(studyData.description.slice(1, studyData.description.length-1).replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

In this case, `$('#description')` is the paragraph tag I'm writing to. `studyData` is my JSON object, and `description` is my key with a multi-line value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was just working on...very helpful, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simple try String(); to remove the quotes.

Refer the first example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp

Thank me later.

PS: TO MODs: don't mistaken me for digging the dead old question. I faced this issue today and I came across this post while searching for the answer and I'm just posting the answer.

Comment: Perfet! Use String() instead of JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is making a JSON string in your example. Either don't use the `JSON.stringify()` or if you ever do have JSON data coming back and you don't want quotations, Simply use `JSON.parse()` to remove quotations around JSON responses! Don't use regex, there's no need to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a need to replace any quotes, this is a perfectly formed JSON string, you just need to convert JSON string into object.This article perfectly explains the situation : [Link](http://blog.mycampusnotes.com/parse-json-string-over-ajax-using-csharp/)

Example :

```
success: function (data) {

        // assuming that everything is correct and there is no exception being thrown
        // output string {"d":"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        // now we need to remove the double quotes (as it will create problem and 
        // if double quotes aren't removed then this JSON string is useless)
        // The output string : {"d":"{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        // The required string : {"d":{username:"hi",email:"hi@gmail.com",password:"123"}"}
        // For security reasons the d is added (indicating the return "data")
        // so actually we need to convert data.d into series of objects
        // Inbuilt function "JSON.Parse" will return streams of objects
        // JSON String : "{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"
        console.log(data);                     // output  : Object {d="{"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"}"}
        console.log(data.d);                   // output : {"username":"hi","email":"hi@gmail.com","password":"123"} (accessing what's stored in "d")
        console.log(data.d[0]);                // output : {  (just accessing the first element of array of "strings")
        var content = JSON.parse(data.d);      // output : Object {username:"hi",email:"hi@gmail.com",password:"123"}" (correct)
        console.log(content.username);         // output : hi 
        var _name = content.username;
        alert(_name);                         // hi

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation in a Promise just solved doing a cast as (String)

```
export async function getUserIdByRole(userRole: string): Promise<string> {
  const getRole = userData.users.find((element) => element.role === userRole);

  return String (getRole?.id);
}
```