# Json object with double quotation marks

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have the simple web api

```
public DateTime PostSpotDate(SpotDay spot) 
{ 
        return DateTime.Now;         
}
```

It returns this string on the client:

```
""2014-06-02T11:55:49.9331121+02:00""
```

Why do I get double quotation marks?
Obviously I cannot parse this date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quote, it was already explain here : [remove double quotes from Json return data using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598477/remove-double-quotes-from-json-return-data-using-jquery)

You will maybe not use the same functions, but it's basically the same method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no date format in JSON, so the server returns it as a string. The JSON format for a string contains quotation marks.

When you display the JSON string in the console (I suppose that's where you see it), the string is shown with quotation marks.

To get the actual string value returned from the server, you parse the JSON string. That will return a string object that contains just the text representation of the date, which you can parse into a `Date` value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you could choose to return a string representation of the DateTime object:

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

You can pass parameters to `ToString` in order to format the date into a more suitable form for parsing or to get rid of components you don't care about, using [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. As you say, It will be much easier to format the DateTime, on the server side, and not on the client.