# How to parse Cosmosdb insert return value of (insertedIds)

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

When I insert an object into CosmosDB (MongoDB API), the result contains a property `insertedIds`.

When I `console.log(insertedIds)` I get

```
[ 5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbb,
5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbc,
5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbd ]
```

and the `typeof()` is an `object`, for each element, although I'm not sure why - they just seem to be strings.

When I go through and `JSON.stringify` each element, I get (with surrounding double quotes) `"5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbb","5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbc","5a6c46c85ac3cc4bb01ebcbd"`

What is the right way to parse a CosmosDB Insert Result, and get the insertedIds as an array of strings?

Do I really have to go through and "stringify" then "de-string by removing quotes" for each returned Id? That is a huge overhead with large arrays.

*Note: I believe this has something to do with MongoDB's bson/strict json: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/ but still not sure how to parse it.*

Comment: Note that MongoDB and CosmosDB are two different products from two different companies. CosmosDB attempts to provide a MongoDB-compatible interface, but there's nothing from MongoDB underneath. As a result, many things that should work on MongoDB simply doesn't work or work differently in CosmosDB.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following example:

> JSON.parse(this_is_double_quoted);
>
> JSON.parse("House");

.parse would return the value without quotes. more information can be found in the following post: [remove double quotes from Json return data using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598477/remove-double-quotes-from-json-return-data-using-jquery)

Comment: thanks, but I would like to avoid having to de-stringify each ID individually as I mentioned...if I'm getting back 10-100k ids in an array, having to parse each one individually is huge overhead. And `JSON.parse(arrayOfStringsWithExtraneousDoubleQuotes) ` doesn't work. Is there no way to get back the raw ID strings directly?