# unable to show dynamic value in the dropdown list available in the table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html table with multiple rows and one of the column has the dropdown list which should populate the values dynamically.
My code has some issue to show the value in the dropdown list in the table, i want to show same value in all the dropdown list shown under 'Select Product' column.

Demo link : http://plnkr.co/edit/roklRKCLjjVeOPe1df4m?p=preview

Sample code below:

```js
// Populate the dropdown with the value
function populateSelect(ids) {
    var productDropdown = $("#product");
    console.log("productDropdown value : " +productDropdown);
    $.each(ids, function() {
        $("<option />").appendTo(productDropdown);
    });
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="populateSelect('TestProduct')">
<table id="productTable" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PID</th>
            <th>Select Product</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>100</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                      <select name="filter_for" id="product">
                         <option value=""> </option>
                         </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>200</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                      <select name="filter_for" id="product">
                         <option value=""> </option>
                         </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>300</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                      <select name="filter_for" id="product">
                         <option value=""> </option>
                         </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>400</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                      <select name="filter_for" id="product">
                         <option value=""> </option>
                         </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

Note : In the above code i'm trying to show the value 'TestProduct' in all the dropdown's shown in the 'Select Product' column.

Comment: $.each takes in an array/object, 'TestProduct' is a string

Answer (score 1):

To have all the dropdowns with the value 'Test Product', use the following code, you don't need a loop for this.

```
function populateSelect(ids) {
    var productDropdown = $(".dropdown select");
    console.log("productDropdown va " + productDropdown);
    $(`<option>${ids}</option>`).appendTo(productDropdown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into is with the way you're initializing the data `body onload="populateSelect('TestProduct');` First of all, in order to successfully `$.each()` through the ids, you'll need to pass them as an `array` rather than a `string`.

Since you have jQuery, I'd recommend using `$(document).ready(function(){});` like so:

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that when you call your `$.each()` function the first time, the callback function needs the parameters of `index` and `value`, so you can iterate through them as `key => value` pairs if that's what you're choosing to do. Otherwise, you could just use the `value` parameter in your option-build like:

`var option = '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>';`

```
function populateSelect(ids) {
    console.log(ids);
    var productDropdown = $(".product");
    //console.log("productDropdown va " + productDropdown);
    $.each(ids, function(index, value) {
        var option = '<option value="'+index+'">' + value + '</option>';
        $.each(productDropdown, function(){
            $(this).append(option);
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    populateSelect(['TestProduct', 'TestProduct2']);
});
```

Also, you're using a non-unique ID `#product` for each of your dropdowns. IDs should be unique, so I've written the code using `.product` as a class instead. The new HTML:

```
<table id="productTable" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>PID</th>
        <th>Select Product</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>100</td>
         <td class="dropdown">
                  <select name="filter_for" class="product">
                     <option value=""> </option>
                     </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>200</td>
         <td class="dropdown">
                  <select name="filter_for" class="product">
                     <option value=""> </option>
                     </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>300</td>
         <td class="dropdown">
                  <select name="filter_for" class="product">
                     <option value=""> </option>
                     </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>400</td>
         <td class="dropdown">
                  <select name="filter_for" class="product">
                     <option value=""> </option>
                     </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please find the updated code demo http://plnkr.co/edit/3J4mJqznsIY7rEVtvvqG?p=preview . The value is shown in the quotations in the drop down list in the table. Any inputs to not to show the quotations in the dropdown list.

Comment: I think this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598477/remove-double-quotes-from-json-return-data-using-jquery will help with that problem for you!